# Python datetime subtraction while ignoring weekend days

Tags: python

I'm familiar with the timedelta method in Python for subtracting days from the current date (below); however I'm curious how I could go about getting it to automatically skip over weekends.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
target_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=dayoffset)
```

So for example, 2019-Oct-08 less 3 days would be 2019-Oct-03 (as the 5th and 6th are weekend days). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `datetime.weekday()`, it returns date to a value from 0-6, while 5 and 6 are the weekend days.

[Read more on this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984741/loop-through-dates-except-for-weekends)

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
def diff_day(start, end):
    delta = timedelta(days=1)
    d = start
    diff = 0
    weekend = [5, 6]
    while d < end:
        if d.weekday() not in weekend:
            diff += 1
        d += delta
    return diff
```

```py
>>>start = datetime(2019,10,3)
>>>end = datetime(2019,10,8)
>>>diff_day(start, end)
3
```