# Listing the previous N business days

Tags: python

I've seen about 30 similar posts to this, but nothing really doing exactly what I'm looking for and some which just don't work..

I'm trying to return a list of N business dates, to then iterate through a dictionary and pull data out according to the corresponding dates.

Assuming the current date is:

```
refreshed = str(data['Meta Data']['3. Last Refreshed'])
```

For completion, the value of above right now is:`2020-1-30`

I want to be able to calculate *n* days prior to this date..

I don't *really* want to import a bunch of funky modules, and have tried a function using a loop and `datetime.date.isoweekday()` - but I always come across an issue when passing `refreshed` in.

One of the main issues I'm seeing with some of the examples elsewhere is where the examples are calculating the dates from `datetime.date.today()` - seemingly it's fine to pass that to `isoweekday()` but I can't pass `refreshed` to `isoweekday()` to calculate it's `0-6` reference. I've tried using `strfrtime()` to reformat the date into a suitable format for `isoweekday` but to no avail.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Loop through dates except for week-ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984741/loop-through-dates-except-for-weekends)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Subtracting days from a date

You can subtract 30 days from a `datetime.datetime` object by subtracting a `datetime.timedelta` object:

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.today()
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 31, 10, 20, 0, 704133)
>>> datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(30)
datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 1, 10, 19, 49, 680385)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-01-30', '%Y-%m-%d') - datetime.timedelta(30)
datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 31, 0, 0)
```

### Skipping week-ends by subtracting 7 days instead of 5

We are starting from date `d` and you want to subtract `N=30` non-week-end days. A general way could be:

- Figure out which day of the week is `d`;
- Figure out how many week-ends there are between `d` and `d-N`;
- Remove the appropriate number of days.

However, you want to subtract 30 days, and 30 is a multiple of 5. This makes things particularly easy: when you subtract 5 days from a date, you are guaranteed to encounter exactly one week-end in those five days. So you can immediately remove 7 days instead of 5.

Removing 30 days is the same as removing 6 times 5 days. So you can remove 6 times 7 days instead, which is achieved by subtracting `datetime.timedelta(42)` from your date.

Note: this accounts for week-ends, but not for special holidays.

### Skipping week-ends iteratively

You can test for days of the week using [`.weekday()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday). This is already answered on this other question: [Loop through dates except for week-ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984741/loop-through-dates-except-for-weekends)

Comment: I only want to subtract business days, and thus skip weekends. Also the above mentioned variable containing the date (refreshed) is not guaranteed to be today().. so I need to be able to pass in an arbitrary date and say 'subtract N business days from X date'

Comment: I used `today()` as an example to get a date. Of course you can do it with any date. The last example is with `datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-01-30', '%Y-%m-%d')`. I don't know if the values you are manipulating are strings like `"2020-01-30"`, which you can parse with `datetime.datetime.strptime`, or are already `datetime.datetime` objects. I didn't realise you weren't interested in week-ends; I'll edit my answer. I suggest you also edit your question to make it more obvious.

Comment: Thank you. This answer didn't get me to exactly where I want to be, but it got me close enough and gave me enough hints to work it out. I realise that my new concerns should really be a different question as it's veering out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add N days using a timedelta:

```
data['Meta Data']['3. Last Refreshed'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Meta Data']['3. Last Refreshed']) + pd.to_timedelta(4, unit="D")
```

Replace 4 with your n days.

Comment: This doesn't work.  print(pd.to_datetime(refreshed) - pd.to_datetime(NDAYS, unit="D"))   returns   18562 days 00:00:00