# Date subtract except weekend within parse function not working

Tags: python, datetime

Python date subtract except weekend within parse function not working

I saw other question solution for counting is fixed the input
[Loop through dates except for weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984741/loop-through-dates-except-for-weekends)

But I want to stepforward to make various date input possible, thanks

```
import numpy as np
import re
import  datetime
from datetime import date,  datetime, time ,timedelta
from dateutil import parser
def date_array_operation(input_string1,input_string2,op):
 
    param1_date_only = input_string1.split(" ")
    param2_date_only = input_string2.split(" ")
 
    date1_parse = parser.parse(param1_date_only[0])
    date2_parse = parser.parse(param2_date_only[0])
 
    param1_date_only_new = param1_date_only[0].replace('/','-')
    param2_date_only_new = param2_date_only[0].replace('/','-')
 
    is_d2_bigger = date2_parse > date1_parse


    start = date1_parse
    end = date2_parse
    delta = timedelta(days=1)
    d = start
    diff = 0
    weekend = set([5, 6])
    while d <= end:
        if d.weekday() not in weekend:
            diff += 1
        d += delta
 
 
    return is_d2_bigger, diff ;
 
param1 = '2017/09/03 07:11:00'
param2 = '2017-09-05 07:11:00'
param_op = 'hour'
param_result = date_array_operation(param1,param2,param_op)
 
print(param_result)
```

> output: (True, 2)

**but expect output should be (True, 1)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why the diff is 2? it is because the range your date are 3:

param1 = '2017/09/03 07:11:00'

param2 = '2017-09-05 07:11:00'

and the weekday result is : 6, 0, 1

and in your logic if the weekday is not in set([5, 6]).

it's mean that you in to the condition 2 times.

that is why the diff is 2

Answer (score 0):

so should be `weekend = set([0, 6])` not `weekend = set([5, 6])`
*Python DateTime weekday()*

> 0 Monday
> 1 Tuesday
> 2 Wednesday
> 3 Thursday
> 4 Friday
> 5 Saturday
> 6 Sunday

```
import numpy as np
import re
import  datetime
from datetime import date,  datetime, time ,timedelta
from dateutil import parser
def date_array_operation(input_string1,input_string2,op):
 
    param1_date_only = input_string1.split(" ")
    param2_date_only = input_string2.split(" ")
 
    date1_parse = parser.parse(param1_date_only[0])
    date2_parse = parser.parse(param2_date_only[0])
 
    param1_date_only_new = param1_date_only[0].replace('/','-')
    param2_date_only_new = param2_date_only[0].replace('/','-')
 
    is_d2_bigger = date2_parse > date1_parse


    start = date1_parse
    end = date2_parse
    delta = timedelta(days=1)
    d = start
    diff = 0
    weekend = set([0, 6])
    while d <= end:
        if d.weekday() not in weekend:
            diff += 1
        d += delta
 
 
    return is_d2_bigger, diff ;
 
param1 = '2017/09/17 07:11:00'
param2 = '2017-09-11 07:11:00'
param_op = 'hour'
param_result = date_array_operation(param1,param2,param_op)
 
print(param_result)
```